# Los vídeos y las imágenes se superponen a mi menú

Tags: html5, css3

Buen día

Por favor solicito su ayuda con la siguiente pregunta.
En mi web en la pagina de inicio hay un vídeo que en modo *dispositivo móvil* al realizar scroll se superpone a mi logo de cabecera y da un efecto feo...

Lo mismo pasa si entran a la pestaña de recetas y en la parte de recetas costa al bajar y ver la galería, las imágenes también se superponen al logo.

> Tengo entendido que tiene que ver algo con el `z-index` o `position: fixed` pero no estoy seguro

les dejo la dirección de mi pagina para mayor referencia

https://www.tipicoecuador.com

Es mi primera pagina web la he hecho desde 0, así que si encuentran algo mal o necesitan el código con gusto lo subiré

Desde ya agradecimientos y saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu pronta respuesta la verdad ya esta solucionado con la respuesta que me has dado

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo mucho usar la consola del navegador para chequear cambios mas rapido!

> En el archivo media.css en la linea 12, en la clase `.menu_bar` tenes que añadir `z-index: 99;`

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente el atributo css `position` y el `z-index` son la clave, te voy a colocar dos ejemplo uno como te esta pasando y el segundo como debería de ser:

**Con el video tapando el logo**:

```css
.container{
  border:1px solid red;
  height: 1200px;
}

.logo{
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  z-index:1;
}

.video{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="https://www.tipicoecuador.com/img/logo1-2.png" width="500" height="150">
  </div>
  <div class="video">
     <iframe width="100%" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JzjVokgcJys?rel=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Aquí el video NO tapa al logo:**

```css
.container{
  border:1px solid red;
  height: 1200px;
}

.logo{
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  z-index:2;
}

.video{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="https://www.tipicoecuador.com/img/logo1-2.png" width="500" height="150">
  </div>
  <div class="video">
     <iframe width="100%" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JzjVokgcJys?rel=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```